# symfony2 @Template in Controller

Tags: php, symfony

I am using routing by annotations and this is what my controller has:

> ```
> /**
>  * @Route("/", name="_index")
>  * @Template()
>  */
> ```

I understand routes but can someone explain what @Template() is doing there and how can I use it? I could not find any documentation about this.

Thanks...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The @Template annotation associates a controller with a template name:

More info here: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/view.html

Comment: Thank you, that was what I needed to understand it. I dont know why in google it did not come up as a result.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to this answer (btw, is correct). You should add the suffix ".html.twig" in case you're using the TWIG engine to render the templates.

Your should look like this

```
/**
 * @Template("MyOwnBundle:Default:myOwnView.html.twig")
 */
public function showAction()
{
     ... bla bla bla
     ... more bla bla
}
```

In this case, you're forcing the showAction() to use a custom template. If the @Template() is empty, your showAction() will looking for the associated template by convention.

Hope this helps.. if not, only "decorates" a little bit more the answer.

Comment: yes, for some reason usual template name: MyOwnBundle:Default:myOwnView doesn't work, it requires .html.twig extension